# Call startActionMode from a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, contextmenu

I'm tring to launch contexual action mode menu from a fragment when a button is clicked. I'm not sure how to call "startActionMode()" from an onClick method in my fragment.

MyFragment

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    ...
    
    private var mActionMode: ActionMode? = null 
    
    // when this button is clicked it should launch the Contextual Action Bar (CAB) 
    fun myCAB() {
        // Check to see CAB is currenty active. 
        if(mActionMode != null) return        
        mActionMode = mActivity.startActionMode(actionModeCallback)
    }

    // ActionMode.Callback interface, handles actions for contextual CAB
    private val actionModeCallback: ActionMode.Callback = object : ActionMode.Callback {
         ... 
    }
}
```

I've tried using

- requireActivity,
- Referencing the activity from onAttach(activity: Activity),

Both options return a type miss match.
Required: androidx.appcompt.view.ActtionMode?
Found: android.view.ActionMode?

Comment: Change import of import android.view.ActionMode to import androidx.appcompt.view.ActtionMode

Comment: I'm currently importing androidx.appcomp.view.ActionMode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the Activity and then call startSupportAction Mode.

```
mActionMode = (activity as MainActivity?)!!.startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback)
```

Here's what it looks like in the code.

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {
    ...

    private var mAction: ActionMode? = null

    fun myCAB() {
        if(mActionMode!= null) return
      
        // as casts the type if is successful or returns null
        mAction = (activity as MainActiivty?)!!.startSupportActionMode(actionModeCallback)
    } 

    private val actionModeCallback: ActionMode.Callback = object : ActionModeCallback {
        ... 
    }
}
```